# Huge dip in npm libraries/framework downloads. Anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When looking at npmtrends.com, I've noticed that nearly every npm library/framework took a huge dip in downloads at the beginning of June, 2018.

Does anyone know why this is? Maybe npm went down or everyone took a break for the summer?

[image]

Comment: Or maybe npm got better at caching

Comment: If I remember correctly, npm released a breaking version earlier in the year. Perhaps they were feeling the after-effects of it in June. See: 
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/linux/botched-npm-update-crashes-linux-systems-forces-users-to-reinstall/

Comment: I added a picture to help illustrate what OP is describing. The effect was temporary, and wouldn't easily be explained by a break that happened in February.

Comment: It seems more like their monitoring went down for about 18 hours..

Comment: I'm curious why angular added 700k downloads per week afterwards?

Comment: Yea, these are old good points & questions. And thanks warrior for adding the pic of what I was talking about. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to have been a problem in updating the counts on npm, Inc.'s side:

> We're investigating a known issue with download counts not being updated properly in the past few days.
>   Posted […] Jun 04, 2018 - 17:30 UTC

(Quote from https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/b4ktc38pypd1.)